# Not able to start the ignite server through java code

Tags: ignite

I am using ignite native and using atomicity as TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT when I am trying the load the old storage which was configured with amoticity TRNASACTIONAL it is giving the Unknown page type issue after deleting the `.dat` file but if I am using new storage it is working fine. Can anybody help me?

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown page type: 10009 pageId: 0002ffff00000006"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE "DFM"."ANSWER_TYPE_ENUM" (_KEY VARCHAR INVISIBLE NOT NULL,_VAL OTHER INVISIBLE,"ID" VARCHAR,"ENUM_VALUE" VARCHAR) engine "org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.H2TableEngine" [50000-197]
```

Comment: Can you please describe old storage - new storage relation in detail?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen errors like these, but I would say that `TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT` is experimental and should be avoided for now.